# "Simplify" or "Evaluate" an expression until it is expreseed in terms of some other variables

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions

Let's say we have the following relation between different variables:

```
AV^2 + BV^2 == 10
DV^2 - CV^2 == 10
FV^2 - EV^2 == 10
BV*DV == 10
AV*FV == 10
CV*EV == 10
CV == AV/BV
```

Here, AV is a symbol and not A*V. Same goes with other variable names.

I want Mathematica to keep "simplifying" until the initial expression turns into something that only has the desired variables I specify.

Here is an example:

`CV + 10/CV` in terms `DV` an `FV`.

```
CV + 10/CV = (10 + CV^2)/CV
(10 + CV^2)/CV = DV^2/CV because 10 + CV^2 = DV^2
DV^2/CV = DV*(DV/CV) = DV*((10/BV)/(AV/BV)) = DV*10/AV
DV*10/AV = DV*FV because 10/AV = FV
```

This will finally make `CV + 10/CV` equal to `DV*FV` which is the desired simplified value.

Can I do something like this in Mathematica? Basically, I just want it to keep changing an expression using given relations until it only contains desired variables.

Is there any function in Mathematica which will keep substituting value of other variables, until I finally have the result only in terms of desired variables?

Comment: `D` and `E`is a build-in function you can't use it ?

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk I am changing them to some other variables now. :)

Comment: Look at `Solve`, `Reduce`, `Eliminate` and related functions.

Comment: @LukasLang I am familiar with them but don't know how to use them together to do this particular task. :)

Comment: It seems that you have 7 equations for 6 variables, do not you?

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch I am not trying to solve those equations for variable values. Instead of considering those 7 as equations think of them as identities to be used to convert `CV + 10/CV` into `DV*FV`. :)

Comment: @iKnowNothing It is not important, if you are trying or not to solve these equations. It is important that they are overdetermined. Whatever you are doing is after that wrong, unless they are degenerated.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch What if they are identities?

Comment: This is the case that they degenerate. Did you read my comment? So, it is the first task to check. All the rest - afterward.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch I don't understand. :) These were actual Trigonometric identities where 1 was replaced by 10. `AV` is `SIN`, `BV` is `COS`. `DV` is `SEC` and `EV` is `TAN`. `FV` is `COSEC` and `GV` is `COT`.

I was looking for a more general approach because I want to evaluate an expression in terms of other trigonometric ratio by only using a specific set of identities.

Comment: @iKnowNothing You used the symbol `==`. This automatically makes your relations to be equations. As such they can be solved. If you try to solve them, Mma returns empty curly braces indicating that this system has no solution. If you, further, remove one of these equations in some cases Mma can find a solution. For instance try to remove the very last equation and solve. May be, this will help.